# C# how to extend and pass a parameter to an attribute

Tags: c#

I'm adding attributes to dynamically created parameters. One attribute implements interface IItemsSource and is used like this:

```
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes;

public class MySourceObject
{
    [ItemsSource(typeof(MyCustomItemsSource))]
    public string SelectedString { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomItemsSource : IItemsSource
{
    public MyCustomItemsSource()
    {
    }

    public ItemCollection GetValues()
    {
        ItemCollection strings = new ItemCollection();
        strings.Add("A");
        strings.Add("B");
        strings.Add("C");

        // Here I want to add some items from a collection, passed to the class somehow

        return strings;
    }
}
```

How can I pass a list of custom object to MyCustomItemsSource constructor?

Comment: Do you wanna know how to send items to the class MyCustomItemsSource so you can add to your string Collection?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want

Comment: And how it is related to the Attribute?

Comment: Firstly, you need to add ctor that takes your list: `public MyCustomItemsSource(List<object> list)`. Secondly, you can pass only some kind of constants to your attribute from it usages, so this `int g = 5;
 [MyCustomItemsSource(new int[]{g+6})]` would not be work. As alternative you can declary a fileds in `MyCustomItemsSource` and use `Reflection` to set this fields for object wich is applied this attribute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/825504/bruno-avelar - how can I usethis decoration [ItemsSource(typeof(MyCustomItemsSource))] with a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not clear what you want to do with the data. You don’t have this type’s instance at the time you create the attribute. This attribute isn’t an instance of an object so you cannot pass any arguments so you must create the object at runtime, and you can do so with reflection.

You can use:

```
IItemsSource myObject = Activator.CreateInstance<IItemsSource>(obj1, obj2,...);
```

---

Update:
As I understand, you want to pass the type and then values to add to the list so you could add

```
public interface IItemsSource
{
    List<string> GetValues();
}
class ItemsSourceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IItemsSource Instance { get; set; }
    public ItemsSourceAttribute(Type type, params string[] listParams)
    {
        if (!typeof(IItemsSource).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            throw new ArgumentException($"IItemsSource is not assignable from {type.Name}.");

        Instance = (IItemsSource) Activator.CreateInstance(type, listParams);
    }
}

public class MyCustomItemsSource : IItemsSource
{
    private List<string> _privateList;

    public MyCustomItemsSource(params string[] list)
    {
        _privateList = list.ToList();
    }

    public List<string> GetValues()
    {
        // _privateList will start with a value of [abc, 123], as we passed on the constructor.
        _privateList.Add("test");
        // now [abc, 123, test]
        return _privateList;
    }
}
```

And then you could add items to the list like that:

```
[ItemsSource(typeof(MyCustomItemsSource), "abc", "123"]
```

Hopefully I got it right. Please comment if you need any adjustments. I wrote this without testing as I'm not with VS on this machine at this moment.

Comment: What namespace contains method for this : Instance = type.CreateInstance<IItemsSource>(listParams);

Comment: Also, can't make this work: Instance = Activator.CreateInstance<IItemsSource>(type, listParams); - says 'No overload for method 'CreateInstance' takes 2 arguments'

Comment: this works : Instance = (IItemsSource)Activator.CreateInstance(type, listParams); ... But it gives an error 'Constructor on type 'Ensign.MasonryApp.Helpers.MyCustomItemsSource' not found.' Why? MyCustomItemsSource has a constructor

Comment: My bad, it is Activator.CreateInstance. Going to replicate and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks, got your code working! And found out, that the object I am using (Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid) will not work with a parametrized constructor of MyCustomItemsSource :( Nevertheless, thank you for your help